# Joining two tables on multiple conditions conditional to the first join field using SQL

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables

```
Tbl_1
Mat_Id     Mat_desc
1001       ABC
1002       CDS
           MNK
           ELP
2003       STX
```

And

```
Tbl_2
Mat_Id     Mat_desc
1004       TSS
1002       CDS
           MNK
2045       EXP
2003       STX
```

I want to join Tbl_1 and Tbl_2 as left join ON two conditions.
If `Mat_Id` in Tbl_1 is present, then ON `Mat_Id` Else ON `Mat_desc`.

So the final Table should look like

```
Mat_Id    Mat_desc   
1001       NULL <---Being joined on Mat_Id
1002       CDS  <---Being joined on Mat_Id
           MNK  <---Being joined on Mat_desc
           NULL <---Being joined on Mat_desc
2003       STX  <---Being joined on Mat_Id
```

If I try

```
SELECT a."Mat_Id",b."Mat_desc FROM Tbl_1 a
LEFT OUTER JOIN Tbl_2 b
ON a."Mat_Id" = b."Mat_Id"
AND a."Mat_desc" = b."Mat_desc"
```

Then it may not work.

Any hints on how to make this possible?

Answer (score 0):

If `mat_id` is `null` any `=` condition on it will return false. You need the `or` logical operator between the two conditions, not `and`. To be extra safe and make sure you don't match `mat_desc`s on rows that have `mat_id`s, you should also explicitly check it:

```sql
SELECT a."Mat_Id",b."Mat_desc"
FROM Tbl_1 a
LEFT OUTER JOIN Tbl_2 b
ON a."Mat_Id" = b."Mat_Id" OR (a."Mat_Id" IS NULL AND a."Mat_desc" = b."Mat_desc")
-- Here -------------------^
```

Comment: Wouldn't this slow the operation? I am talking records ~ 15000 in Tbl_1 and > 50000 in Tbl_2